# Grails convert Blob column to deserialize into object

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-2.3

Given below domain class, I want to convert the Blob data into Java object by deserializing the bytes. What is the approach to follow? Do I need to specify any converter to GORM to invoke it after fetching the data from DB?

```
class SpringMessage {

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'staging_oracle'
        message type: 'blob', column: 'message_bytes'
        createdDate type: Date, column: 'created_date'
    }
    static constraints = {
    }

    String messageId
    Blob message //It holds the serialized bytes
    Date createdDate
}
```

Ideally I do not want to have "Blob" property on the domain class. Instead I want to declare actual Java class type (ex: `Foo message`) but hope to specify some type of converter in mapping. i.e

```
static mapping = {
   message type:'blob', converter:FooDeserializer
}
```

Note the converter argument for message column in mapping. Is there such a feature in Grails? Or any other feature which allows me to do some `post processing` after the data is fetched from GORM?
I use Grails 2.3.3.

As of now, I do the deserialization outside the grails generated findBy method. I was hoping that there would be some callback method which might be called by findByXXX implementations to do this convertion from Blob to java object.

```
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(springMessage.message.getBinaryStream())
        Message<?> message = is.readObject()
```